# Multiplying matrix by vector to get result with given properties.

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $M$ be a matrix with $n$ rows and $m$ colums, filled with values $-1,0,1$ in a way that there is at least one non-zero value in each row. Will there always exist a column vector $A$ with size $m$ that contains only integral values and if we multiply $M$ by $A$, we will get a vector whose all entries are non-zero and their absolute value is less or equal to $4$? For example, if
$$
M=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -1 \\
1 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
0 & 1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$
then $A$ could be for example $\begin{bmatrix} 2 \\ 1 \end{bmatrix}$, and their multiple would be $M\times A=
\begin{bmatrix}
1 \\
3 \\
2 \\
1 \\
\end{bmatrix}
$. All entries of their product are non-zero and their absolute values are less or equal to $4$, so such a vector $A$ exists for this matrix. Will such a vector exist for any matrix?